# Socket status: connect_error+connect nodejs socket.io with flutter

Tags: node.js, flutter, socket.io

I am trying to connect socket.io of nodejs, with flutter.

I have done many attempts, and used almost all of the available packages. Also, I have tried with emulator, and real device.

Finally, I was able to connect to the socket, but there is an error in the call back.

Below is the code:

```
initSocket() async {
    SocketIO socket =
    SocketIOManager().createSocketIO("http://127.0.0.1:3000/", "/", socketStatusCallback: _socketStatus);
    socket.subscribe("news", _onSocketInfo);
    socket.init();
    socket.connect();
 }
```

Below is the code error:

Socket status: connect_error

Any advice about this issue?

Thanks,